# Parse html files with variable element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a challenge with my downloaded html files to parse in the appropriate format.
In the div *DIV id=article_participants class="content_part hid"*, there are executives named (for example like below Dror Ben Asher, Ori Shilo and Guy Goldberg): 
So executives vary per html page, but the setup of div's and html is the same.

```
<DIV id=article_participants class="content_part hid">
<P>Redhill Biopharma Ltd. (NASDAQ:<A title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/rdhl" symbolSlug="RDHL">RDHL</A>)</P>
<P>Q4 2014 <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">Earnings</SPAN> Conference <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f38686">Call</SPAN></P>
<P>February 26, 2015 9:00 AM ET</P>
<P><STRONG>Executives</STRONG></P> 
<P>Dror Ben Asher - CEO</P>
<P>Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations</P>
<P>Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer</P>
<P><STRONG>Analysts</STRONG></P>
<p>Scott Henry - Roth Capital</p>
</div>
```

Later on in the html (in DIV id=article_qanda class="content_part hid"), the executives are answering questions. These answers (to be recognized by `<P><STRONG><SPAN class=answer>Ori Shilo</SPAN></STRONG></P>`

In dropbox i shared an example of one of htmls i downloaded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uka24w7o5006ole/transcript-86-855.html?dl=0

What my output should be is the following (for all my files in the directory in one csv file):
Executives /// Answers /// title of html

My code till now is only for one CEO:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
def find_executive(soup, executive):
    for answer in soup.select(f'p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains({executive}) + p'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True) 
    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))

    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format(func, txt), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Could someone help me in solving this challenge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911893/parse-div-element)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

In the below code replace `'html_folder'` with your `html files folder path`

```
from pathlib import Path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_names(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        soup = bs(f.read())
        names = soup.select('div#article_participants > p')
        return [x.text for x in names]
    return []

html_files = list(map(str, Path('html_folder').rglob('*.html')))
for f in html_files:
    print(get_names(f))
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to find  the executives mentioned in the output you provided and used as search elements in the part of the html file called(DIV id=article_qanda class="content_part hid"), and than the answers they gave?

Answer (score 0):

@abhilb But this only gives the results of div#article_participants. What i need is the executives mentioned in the output you provided and used as search elements in the part of the html file called(DIV id=article_qanda class="content_part hid"), and than the answers they gave.

```
['Banco Latinoamericano de Comercio Exterior, S.A (NYSE:BLX)', 'Q2 2014 Earnings Call', 'July 24, 2014 11:00 am ET', 'Executives', 'Rubens V. Amaral - Chief Executive Officer, President and Director', 'Christopher Schech - Chief Financial Officer and Executive Vice President of Finance ', 'Analysts', 'Yuri R. Fernandes - JP Morgan Chase & Co, Research Division']
['Redhill Biopharma Ltd. (NASDAQ:RDHL)', 'Q4 2014 Earnings Conference Call', 'February 26, 2015 9:00 AM ET', 'Executives', 'Dror Ben Asher - CEO', 'Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations', 'Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer', 'Analysts', 'Scott Henry - Roth Capital', 'Vernon Bernardino - MLV', 'Ramakanth Swayampakula - H.C. Wainwright']
```